# How to unit test a method which has a return value and dependent on my other class?

Tags: java, unit-testing, testing

I'm a newbie at java unit testing. How to unit test a method which has a return value and dependent on my other class?

The following codes convert a `ResponseBody` to an object. The `parser.fromJson(json, type)` and `decodeToJson(value)` are my custom mthods.
How should I unit test the method `convert(ResponseBody)`?

```
public class MyConverter<T> {
    public MyConverter(JsonParser parser, Type type, Cipher  cipher) {
        this.parser = parser;
        this.type = type;
        this.cipher = cipher;
    }

    public T convert(ResponseBody value) throws IOException {
        String json;
        if (cipher == null) {
            json = value.string();
        } else {
            json = decrypt(value);
        }
        return parser.fromJson(json, type);
    }

    public String decrypt(ResponseBody value) {
        //Just decrypt the ResponseBody to String.
        ...
    }
}
```

I already have some test codes. Here is my test case.

```
@Test
public void testConvert_withCipher() throws Exception {
    converter = spy(new MyConverter(mockParser, mockType, null));
    ResponseBody dummyResponse = ResponseBody.create(MediaType.parse("application/json"), "{text:'Dummy response'}");

    converter.convert(dummyResponse);

    verify(converter).decrypt(eq(dummyResponse));
    verify(mockParser).fromJson(anyString(), eq(mockType));
}
```

I only verify the vital dependent mock objects were interacted with correctly. Should I verify the returned value?

Hope someone can help me, thanks!

Comment: What is `ResponseBody`?

Comment: How do you initialize the `parser` object?

Comment: `ResponseBody` is defined in okHttp and contains my server api response.

Comment: You'll have to mock your dependencies using a mocking framework like `Mockito` or `JMock`.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice `parser` is injected by the constructor of `MyConverter`. Sorry, I'll edit my code in question!

Comment: @user2004685 Yes, I have used Mockito to mock JsonParser.  Should I verify the returned value?

Comment: There is no need to verify the return value. You are not writing a Unit Test for `JsonParser` and hence you should not be concerned with what it returns. :)

Comment: @user2004685 Thanks you very much. I have another question. If the `cipher` is null, I should verify `converter.decrypt(value)` is never called. Right? BTW, can you give the answer? Thanks!

Comment: @Sandy Your Welcome! I have provided the answer. If `cipher` is null then you can verify the times `converter` has been called. It should be 0 times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use any of the Mocking Frameworks like `Mockito` or `JMock` to mock the Response.

You don't have to verify the actual value returned from `JsonParser` since you are not writing the Unit Test for `JsonParser` but your class.

If you want to verify the number of times any of your mock has been called then you can do something like this:

```
verify(converter, Mockito.times(1)).decrypt(eq(dummyResponse));
```

This will fail in case your mock has not been called at all or is called more than one time.